# c++ undefined reference using templates

Tags: c++, templates

So I have the following code:

```
template<class T>
class A
{
public:

  class B
  {
  public:
    virtual void Destroy(T obj);
  };

  B &_b;

  A(B b) : _b(b)
  {
  }

  void Go(T obj)
  {
    _b.Destroy(obj);
  }
};

class X : public A<int>::B
{
public:
  void Destroy(int x)
  {
    //do something
  }
};

int main()
{
  X x;
  A<int> a(x);
  a.Go(5);
  return 0;
}
```

But I get a compile error:

```
undefined reference to 'A<int>::B::Destroy(int)'
```

I've seen issues before when doing templates in separate .hpp and .cpp files... but this is all in one file.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a definition for `virtual void Destroy(T obj);`:

- Either in place:

  ```
  class B
  {
  public:
      virtual void Destroy(T obj) { /* here! */ }
      // ==== ALTERNATIVELY: ====
      virtual void Destroy(T obj) = 0;  // pure-virtual
  };
  ```
- Or afterwards:

  ```
  template <typename T>
  void A<T>::B::Destroy(T obj) { /* here. */ }
  ```

In any event, the constructor for `A` should take a reference:

```
A(B & b) : _b(b) { }
//^^^^^
```

Comment: Awesome thanks! I forgot about the `=0` to make it pure-virtual.

Comment: Oh god, I've been misspelling "ALTERNATIVELY" my whole life :(

Answer (score 2):

- `virtual void Destroy(T obj);` isn't implemented. Implement it or mark it as virtual pure `= 0`
- There's no `;` after the definition of `X`
- `a.Go();` is wrong, `Go` should take a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided implementation for `Destroy()` in `B`, e.g.:

```
template<class T>
void A<T>::B::Destroy(T a) {
  // do something
}
```

Note that you also have other compilation errors: missing semicolon after the body of class B and missing argument in call to `Go()`.